# Flutter/Android - compileSdkVersion conflicts loop resolution

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I'm trying to build an apk using a simple:

> flutter build apk

My compileSdkVersion is set to 30, but:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Dias\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bc3a34b42310899696694b82af2012e8\core-1.0.1\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\Dias\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bc3a34b42310899696694b82af2012e8\core-1.0.1\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

So I try add this on build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

and it does not work, then I found that the solution is set compileSdkVersion to 28 then another error was throw:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Projetos\izeus\localizador\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:50:9-54:19: AAPT: error: attribute android:foregroundServiceType not found.
```

Then I found that the solution is set compileSdkVersion to 29, then here we go again to the first error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Dias\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bc3a34b42310899696694b82af2012e8\core-1.0.1\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\Dias\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\bc3a34b42310899696694b82af2012e8\core-1.0.1\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

Well, I don't know what to do, I'm stuck in a compileSdkVersion loop resolution.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this? I'm encountering the same issue where the geolocator plugin asks for version 30 but then permissions handler asks for version 28.

Comment: I update my flutter to environment sdk to ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0". Then I upgrade all dependencies versions from pubspec.yaml, set minSdkVersion to 21 on build.gradle, and now its compiling again.